# Тмутаракань

Tags: топонимика

Интересно происхождение этого названия. Первая ассоциация, конечно, с "тьмой тараканов"))), но, думаю, что это не так. Слово похоже на тюркское.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя собственное Тьмутаракань (Тмутаракань) в настоящее время - Тамань.
В словаре Фасмера Тмут**о**р**о**кань (Тьмуторокань) возводится к тюрк. tamantarkan "определенный сан", др.-тюрк. tаmаn "название сана" и представляет собой притяжательное прилагательное на -io-. В словаре Шведовой говорится, что название Тмутаракань происходит из *тьму-таракань*, первая часть восх. к тюрк. *tümän ‘10 тысяч’, а вторая заимств. из вост.-иран. tarxan ‘окружной судья’, первонач. ‘местность, где под властью судьи тысячи воинов’. В любом случае, как вы предполагали, название восточное (тюркское) по происхождению.

Кстати, посмотрела и о тараканах. И вот что нашла. В Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я.Черных русское **таракан** возводится к заимствованию из польского kаrасzаn "таракан", karakan, karaluch (не очень убедительно, но такая же версия есть и в словаре Фасмера). Польское же karaluch некоторые исследователи производят из нем. Kасkеrlасk "таракан, прусак", а другие -- из тюрк. tarakan (все возвращается на круги своя). В подтверждение тюрк.версии в современном чувашском (представитель булгарской ветви тюркских языков) языке tarakan переводится как "убегающий". Есть комментарий акад. Трубачева, что **таракан** (*торокан*) происходит из уничижительного употребления тюрк. tarkan "сановник" (Где-то мы это уже видели:-)!!!). Версия, имеющая право на существование. Так что связь с тараканами не такая уж призрачная. Но только, конечно, в переносном значении.