# Происхождение слова "таракан"

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю из литературы, до определенного момента в России тараканов не было, и завезли их во время, кажется, Русско-Прусской войны. И тогда тараканов назвали пруссаками.
А откуда взялось слово **таракан**? По-моему, оно появилось раньше, чем насекомое в России (достаточно вспомнить старинную фамилию — Таракановы).
По звучанию мне это слово напоминает тюркское. А как на самом деле?

Comment: Обыденный русский язык и современный сленг, как ни странно, возвращают девнему слову его значение. Вот молодёжное выражение: "тараканим отсюда" - то есть "быстро уходим"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и в случае недавней "росомахи", точное происхождение слова не установлено, и есть множество гипотез. Примечательно, что в обоих случаях одна из гипотез (на основании простой похожести со словами tar-aqan из чувашского - "убегающий") исходит от одного и того же толкователя Рясинена. Строгих обоснований нет.

Answer (score 2):

Тараканов никто не завозил. Это байка народная. 
История несколько другая. Рыжие тараканы (прусаки) вытеснили черных "аборигенов", поскольку оказались более приспособленными к жизни в более цивилизованных "условиях" (они более наглые и меньше боятся человека). Пруссаками же назвали именно рыжих за то, что их хитиновые надкрылья формой сильно напоминают раздвоенные фалды мундира прусских солдат.

Происхождение же слова действительно не очень понятно, но очень уж напрашивается аналогия с Тмутараканью... Во всяком случае фонетика явно не чужда ни русскому, ни древнерусскому. Это стоит учитывать авторам, продвигающим идею безусловного заимствования.

Про версии происхождения названия и Тмутаракании, и таракана см. здесь.
[Тмутаракань](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4653)

Answer (score 1):

По мнению лингвиста И.Г. Добродомова слово «таракан» пришло из Орды и имеет тюркское происхождение. Слово семантически связано с народом многочисленных нахлебников. В Московии, жившей 250 лет в составе Орды.  Термин происходит от ордынского почетного титула «таркан». Перед прочими обывателями Орды тарканы имели важное преимущество: они освобождались от уплаты всех податей. Отсюда московитское преобразование «тороканъ», «таракан» и украинское (русинское) «таркан»
Таким образом, тарканы – это этническая элита Орды из числа исконных монголов, которые составили ядро войска и администрации Чингизидов. Если учесть, что скот облагался налогом, а тараканы нет, то аналогия  очевидна.