# Где была расположена Тьмутаракань, что означает это название и при чем тут тараканы?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Почему город так назывался? При чем тут тараканы?

Comment: Четвёртый раз задаётся этот вопрос. Воспользуйтесь окном Искать!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Тмутаракань](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4653/%d0%a2%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

Тараканы ни при чём.  Одна из версий:

История поселения на месте Тмутаракани восходит к годам до нашей эры. На этом месте было греческой поселение. Потом хозяева и названия менялись. Один из вариантов происхождения слова относится ко временам татаро-монгольского нашествия на Русь.

Последовательность образования названия примерно такая Тумен Тархан - Таматарха - Тмутаракань (Тьмутаракань). Так что Тьмутаракань - переиначенное Тумен Тархан (так слышалось).

Тумен - высшая единица в войске Чингисхана - 10 тыс человек, во главе стоит темник. Отсюда и русское выражение большого числа тьма-тьмущая (это значит 100 млн).

Тарханами назывались лица, имеющие тарханную грамоту от хана о привилегиях или льготах.

Может, эта местность по тарханной грамоте была пожалована какому-нибудь особо отличившемуся тумену, отсюда и название Тумен Тархан (то есть тархан для тумена)

Написание через О -Тьмуторокон, Тмутороконь и прочие -  связаны с оканьем на Руси. А вообще, сейчас историки  всё чаще говорят, что это мистификация и Тьмутаракань никогда Древней Руси не принадлежала, это наши лидеры  дали такой приказ - сфальсифицировать, чтобы иметь право говорить об исторической справедливости.

Answer (score 0):

У тюрков и сейчас есть выражение, употребляемое при разгоне табуна или стада (когда надо отделить молодых животных от взрослых) или остановить стадо, табун перед опасностью (обрыв, вода, железная дорога). При этом кто-то дает команду "Тум- таракай!" – разгоняй по сторонам.
Существует легенда, что при нападении на русские поселения, при захвате в полон(!), так кричали друг другу вороги: "Разбивай на малые группы и угоняй". Так удобнее было угонять и скот, и женщин... Вот это и осталось в языке, в русском трансформировалось в страшную "ТЬМУ-ТАРАКАНЬ"!

Comment: История увлекательная и изложена в свободной от источника манере. Не хватает фактов и ссылок, ну и ответа на вопросы: где и почему?